# can't disable the input elements using jQuery after selecting an option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, element

I was using `jquery 3.4.1` for this
I was trying to disable input elements when the different value selected.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form input[name="spouseName"]').prop("disabled", true);
  $('form input[name="children"]').prop("disabled", true);
  $("form select option [value='married']").change(function() {
    $('form input[name="spouseName"]').prop("disabled", false);
    $('form input[name="children"]').prop("disabled", false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select class="form-control" name="maritalStatus" id="maritalStatus">
    <option value="Married">Married</option>
    <option selected value="UnMarried">UnMarried</option>
    <option value="Male Widow">Male Widow</option>
    <option value="FeMale Widow">FeMale Widow</option>
    <option value="Divorcee">Divorcee</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="spouseName" id="spouseName" aria-describedby="spName" placeholder="Spose Name">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="children" id="children" aria-describedby="childrens" placeholder="Children">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `change` event you should check the value of the selected option. Also to remove the attribute you can use [`.removeAttr()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/).

Try the following way:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('form input[name="spouseName"]').prop("disabled", true);
  $('form input[name="children"]').prop("disabled", true);

  $("form select").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'Married'){
      $('form input[name="spouseName"]').removeAttr("disabled")
      $('form input[name="children"]').removeAttr("disabled")
    }
    else{
      $('form input[name="spouseName"]').prop("disabled", true);
      $('form input[name="children"]').prop("disabled", true);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select class="form-control" name="maritalStatus" id="maritalStatus">
    <option value="Married">Married</option>
    <option selected value="UnMarried">UnMarried</option>
    <option value="Male Widow">Male Widow</option>
    <option value="FeMale Widow">FeMale Widow</option>
    <option value="Divorcee">Divorcee</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="spouseName" id="spouseName" aria-describedby="spName" placeholder="Spose Name">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="children" id="children" aria-describedby="childrens" placeholder="Children">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try your required solution with conditions. Please check below code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form input[name="spouseName"]').prop("disabled", true);
  $('form input[name="children"]').prop("disabled", true);
  $("#maritalStatus").change(function() {
    if($(this).val() !=='UnMarried'){
           $('form input[name="spouseName"]').prop("disabled", false);
           $('form input[name="children"]').prop("disabled", false);  
    }else{
     $('form input[name="spouseName"]').prop("disabled", true);
            $('form input[name="children"]').prop("disabled", true);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select class="form-control" name="maritalStatus" id="maritalStatus">
    <option value="Married">Married</option>
    <option selected value="UnMarried">UnMarried</option>
    <option value="Male Widow">Male Widow</option>
    <option value="FeMale Widow">FeMale Widow</option>
    <option value="Divorcee">Divorcee</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="spouseName" id="spouseName" aria-describedby="spName" placeholder="Spose Name">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="children" id="children" aria-describedby="childrens" placeholder="Children">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The "on change" event is related to the select and not the option

So you have to work with "if ... else" in the both cases of values in the select whether "married" or not

Thus i make this change in your code and it works properly

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form input[name="spouseName"]').prop("disabled", true);
  $('form input[name="children"]').prop("disabled", true);
  $("form select").change(function() {
   if(this.value === 'Married'){
    $('form input[name="spouseName"]').prop("disabled", false);
     $('form input[name="children"]').prop("disabled", false);
   }else{
    $('form input[name="spouseName"]').prop("disabled", true);
    $('form input[name="children"]').prop("disabled", true);
   }    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select class="form-control" name="maritalStatus" id="maritalStatus">
    <option value="Married">Married</option>
    <option selected value="UnMarried">UnMarried</option>
    <option value="Male Widow">Male Widow</option>
    <option value="FeMale Widow">FeMale Widow</option>
    <option value="Divorcee">Divorcee</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="spouseName" id="spouseName" aria-describedby="spName" placeholder="Spose Name">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="children" id="children" aria-describedby="childrens" placeholder="Children">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn’t mention whats not working but your onChange wont work.

The css selector has a space

`option [value='married']`

Should be:

`option[value='married']`